# Incorrect data format for value - UTCDate

Tags: utc, quickfix

using Fix 4.2, I am receiving messages like this:

```
8=FIX.4.29=15135=W49=aSERVER56=myNAME34=84823052=20130226-00:43:05.53755=USD/JPY268=1269=2270=92.699271=0272=20130226273=19:43:04274=210=251
```

but my QuickFix implementation is throwing this error:

```
8=FIX.4.29=13935=334=949=myNAME52=20130226-00:43:05.66556=aSERVER45=84823058=Incorrect data format for value371=272372=W373=610=225
```

indicating that tag 272 is in the incorrect format.

Tag 272 is defined in the data dictionary like this:

```
<field number="272" name="MDEntryDate" type="UTCDATE"/>
```

so it looks like the format is correct to me. "20130226".

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems this is a known bug, and will be released in the next release of QuickFix/N (most probably March 2013):

https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/issues/135#issuecomment-14089433